# Is there any way of improving the performance of this SQL Function?

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a table which looks something like

```
Event ID  Date       Instructor
1         1/1/2000    Person 1
1         1/1/2000    Person 2
```

Now what I want to do is return this data so that each event is on one row and the Instructors are all in one column split with a `<br>` tag like  `'Person 1 <br> Person 2'`

Currently the way I have done this is to use a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnReturnInstructorNamesAsHTML
(
    @EventID INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT 
        @result = coalesce(@result + '<br>', '') + inst.InstructorName 
    FROM
        [OpsInstructorEventsView]   inst
    WHERE
        inst.EventID = @EventID

    RETURN @result


END
```

Then my main stored procedure calls it like

```
   SELECT 
        ev.[BGcolour], 
        ev.[Event] AS name, 
        ev.[eventid] AS ID, 
        ev.[eventstart], 
        ev.[CourseType], 
        ev.[Type], 
        ev.[OtherType], 
        ev.[OtherTypeDesc], 
        ev.[eventend], 
        ev.[CourseNo], 
        ev.[Confirmed], 
        ev.[Cancelled], 
        ev.[DeviceID] AS resource_id, 
        ev.Crew, 
        ev.CompanyName , 
        ev.Notes,
        dbo.fnReturnInstructorNamesAsHTML(ev.EventID) as Names
    FROM 
        [OpsSimEventsView] ev
    JOIN
        [OpsInstructorEventsView]   inst
    ON
        ev.EventID = inst.EventID
```

This is very slow, im looking at 4seconds per call to the DB. Is there a way for me to improve the performance of the function? Its a fairly small function so im not sure what I can do here, and I couldnt see a way to work the COALESCE into the SELECT of the main procedure.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: String concatenation (and string functions in general) are not something that SQL will ever do really quickly.  SQL is optimized for set based logic, not iterative recursion.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: a simple way to improve performance would be to remove the join to `[OpsInstructorEventsView]` from the main query, since you aren't currently using any of the fields from it.

Comment: @MarkBannister Thanks, I must have missed that, I had it left in after playing around for a while trying to do this all in one proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
SELECT 
    ev.[BGcolour], 
    ev.[Event] AS name, 
    ev.[eventid] AS ID, 
    ev.[eventstart], 
    ev.[CourseType], 
    ev.[Type], 
    ev.[OtherType], 
    ev.[OtherTypeDesc], 
    ev.[eventend], 
    ev.[CourseNo], 
    ev.[Confirmed], 
    ev.[Cancelled], 
    ev.[DeviceID] AS resource_id, 
    ev.Crew, 
    ev.CompanyName , 
    ev.Notes,
    STUFF((SELECT '<br>'+inst.InstructorName
           FROM [OpsInstructorEventsView]   inst
           WHERE ev.EventID = inst.EventID
           FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 4, '') as Names
FROM 
    [OpsSimEventsView] ev
```

Not sure why you have joined `OpsInstructorEventsView` in the main query. I removed it here but if you needed you can just add it again.

Comment: Thanks, this brings the performance down to about 1 second for 260 rows so its a big improvement over what I had

Answer (score 0):

A few things to look at:

1) The overhead of functions makes them expensive to call, especially in the select statement of a query that could potentially be returning thousands of rows.  It will have to execute that function for every one of them.  Consider merging the behavior of the function into your main stored procedure, where the SQL Server can make better use of its optimizer.

2) Since you are joining on event id in both tables, make sure you have an index on those two columns.  I would expect that you do, given that those both appear to be primary key columns, but make sure.  An index can make a huge difference.

3) Convert your coalesce call into its equivalent case statements to remove the overhead of calling that function.

Comment: `COALESCE` **IS** a case statement as far as the optimizer is concerned.  Subbing it out will only add a few more characters to the query.

Comment: that is true, however, my intent was to remove the overhead of calling the function itself, not to change how it worked.  There will always be some overhead, however minimal, when calling functions in a select clause.  It may or may not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes make it an INLINE Table-Valued SQL function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION fnReturnInstructorNamesAsHTML 
 (  @EventID INT  ) 
 RETURNS Table   
 As 
  Return

  SELECT  InstructorName + '<br>' result 
  FROM OpsInstructorEventsView
  WHERE EventID = @EventID 
  Go
```

Then, in your SQL Statement, use it like this

```
SELECT    ]Other stuff],
    (Select result from dbo.fnReturnInstructorNamesAsHTML(ev.EventID)) as Names   
FROM OpsSimEventsView ev   
   JOIN OpsInstructorEventsView inst   
     ON  ev.EventID = inst.EventID
```

I'm not exactly clear how the query you show in your question is concatenating data from multiple rows in one row of the result, but the problem is that ordinary UDFs are compiled on use, on EVERY use, so for each row in your output result the Query processopr has to recompile the UDF again.  THis is NOT True for an "inline table valued" UDF, as it's sql is folded into the outer sql before it is passed to the SQL optimizer, (the subsystem that generates the statement cache plan) and so the UDF is only compiled once.

Comment: The function I was calling was only returning one value which had the concatenated data containing all Names for the specified eventID, however when I convert it to use the method you suggested I still only get 1 row per name which is the data I start with before using the function :(